# ASP.NET 4.0 worker process consumes 5x more memory in 64bit in comparison to 32bit

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, wow64

I have migrated one ASP.NET v4.0 application to a new server running under a Win2008 Server x64 operating system. Since it seemed to be no problem with the migrated asp.net application when the application pool was set to "Enable 32-bit applications" = False (should be default on x64 IIS), I left it running in 64-bit mode.

Then it turned out, that user sessions are interrupted very often, because the worker process exceeds its virtual memory limit quite soon. From this reason I have tested the same application and the same application pool with just a single modified setting - I toggled the "Enable 32-bit applications" to True to let it run in "WOW64" mode; everyting else remained as it was. I have compared the memory amount consumed by the worker process in both modes using absolutely the same user work scenario and the result was bit shocking to me:

- the workload consumes approx. 150MB while running in WOW64 32-bit mode
- and an identical workload consumes approx 800MB in "default" 64-bit worker process mode.

I have expected that it might happen that the worker process will consume a little more memory in 64-bit mode, but this difference is far too huge.

Is such a huge memory impact considered normal? Is it possible to reduce/fix it somehow?

Comment: We saw something similar - see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/912891. However, I'd be surprised if this was it.

Comment: Any unmanaged code, 3rd party library? It seems you have a **memory leak** in x64 since you get recycling over and over.

Comment: @dash interesting. But that is only for .NET 2.0.

Comment: @dash thanks for the link. Symptoms are similar, but that is related to .NET 2.0.

Comment: @Aliostad The solution references only .NET4 standard assemblies "System.*" - with one exception. It references also Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls assembly - not available anymore in .NET 4.0. This might cause the issue, because since it is not available anymore, it was not updated during upgrade of the solution to .NET4. I originally expected, that the application with this legacy reference would not run in 64-bit mode at all, but it does..only issue is the memory consumption.

Comment: You can profile the web application using a good profiler. Then you will be able to see what consumes the memory and possible identify the root cause. It is not easy to guess from the outside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After more investigation it seems that there is no memory issue.. New server just has more memory and while running on a 64-bit OS application pool simply is allowed to allocate larger memory resource. It looked like a memory leak, but since from a certain amount of allocated RAM the process stops consuming additional memory, it does not seem to be a memory issue at all. Thanks to all respondees..

Comment: which tools you use for troubleshooting ?